# Two Html.BeginForm() on one Razor View

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor

I'm developping a Website in MVC 4.5 with Razor, and I need to put 2 `Html.BeginForm` on the same page. As i've noticed it and read it all over the internet, two forms on the same page ain't working finely.

I tried to use `runat='server'` but that ain't working either, but I saw this post : http://www.quora.com/How-do-I-use-2-forms-in-a-single-ASP-NET-page-running-on-a-server where a dude is saying :

> In MVC, it's extremely easy since you use the Form tag. :-)

Sadly he doesn't precise what should be done, and it's the only clue I still have.

So if anyone has an idea of how I could do this ...

Some more precisions :

Both of my `@using (Html.BeginForm)` are working finely on separated pages, and they're submitting totally different datas. I already thought about mixin them and handle the mix in the controller's method, but this is a way too aweful :/

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Multiple `form` tags should work fine in MVC unless they are nested. Tell us what are the problems you are facing with some code, specially HTML code.

Comment: You also need to be careful how you submit each form, i.e. which submit button controls each form. Could you please explain what it is that is not working?

Comment: In a nutshell, my first form works finely. The second one, on submit, triggers the first one. 
First one : `@using (Html.BeginForm("InstructionSearch", "Search", FormMethod.Post, new { }))`
Second one : `@using (Html.BeginForm("ECN", "Search", new { id = "searchForm"}))`
Both methods exist in my `SearchController`

Comment: That would only happen if you had nested forms (which is invalid html)

Comment: Ok ! I found it ! I had a `onclick` attribute on the 2nd form's submit button ... Thanks everyone for your help, and sorry for bothering you for such a stupid thing :/

Comment: Just for further clarification, the comment about _"2 forms on a page ain't working"_ is **only** relevant  to `ASP.Net Web Forms`  - because the entire page is encapsulated in 1 "main" form (and you can't nest `<form/>`). There are ways around that, but I digress :)

Comment: From what i understood, in ASP .Net with MVC it's possible thanks to the Helpers, but i don't really know why x)

Answer (score 5):

You can have several forms on a page. But they must not be one in another.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("your action name", "your controller ", FormMethod.Post))
{
// code for the first form here
}


@using (Html.BeginForm("your other action name", "your controller ", FormMethod.Post))
{
// code for the second form here
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that "they must **Not** be nested within another HtmlBeginForm"?

Answer (score 2):

Your forms should both be fine, but you need to specify what action they should post to, rather than just leave it as the default, e.g.:

```
@Html.BeginForm("Action1", "Controller1") {
   ... Fields to post to Action1.
}

@Html.BeginForm("ActionX", "ControllerX") {
   ... Fields to post to ActionX
}
```